# c++ How to shuffle/mix a string before cout?

Tags: c++, shuffle

Refer the below code

```
random_shuffle(cq.begin(), cq.end());
cout << cq ;
```

As I understand, I have connected two strings `c` and `q` in to one `cq`. And then I want to shuffle/mix it before `cout`. How do I do that?

Thank You for Your answers in advance

Comment: What is the desired result vs the result you are getting now?

Comment: Your question is unclear.   What do you mean by "connected two strings `c` and `q` in to one `cq`"?     Note that `std::random_shuffle()` was deprecated in C++14, and removed from C++17.   Use `std::shuffle()` instead.

Comment: Hello all, thank You for Your answers. Lets say if I have 10 symbols (numbers and letters) in a string colled cq. How do I mix it before cout?

Comment: I wonder how to use correctly this shuffle() ?

Comment: @AndriusJ: You may want to show a bigger example. Give `cq` an explciit value for demo purposes. What is the output you then get, and what did you expect? This isn't necessarily a bad question, but currently there's too much missing.

Comment: You seem to have already answered your own question. What exactly is the problem? What are you seeing? What are you expecting?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
   std::string str = "StackOverflow";
   std::random_device rd;
   std::mt19937 g(rd());
   std::shuffle(str.begin(), str.end(), g);
   std::cout << str.c_str() << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

You can read more details on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle